# Stack Overflow API for popular tags using date filter - results not making sense

Tags: stackexchange-api

I'm trying to pull the most popular tags between a set of dates. However, the results aren't making sense.

I can't figure out what the date filter does in the context of tags. Is this based on the creation of the tag itself, because the overall most popular tags end up not appearing when I filter down to a month range.

For example, the query below shows "confluent-platform" as the most popular tag, though when I do a search on the website, popular tags appear far more often.

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?fromdate=1564617600&todate=1566864000&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow

Is there a way to use the tag API to get the most popular terms within a time frame or do I have to use the question search for this?

Answer (score 1):

The "issue" here appears to be caused by the `fromdate` and `todate` parameters. Without those, you get indeed the most popular tags:

```
{
  "has_synonyms": true,
  "is_moderator_only": false,
  "is_required": false,
  "count": 2082163,
  "name": "javascript"
},
{
  "has_synonyms": true,
  "is_moderator_only": false,
  "is_required": false,
  "count": 1710013,
  "name": "java"
},
....
```

Why does this happen? Because:

> `fromdate` and `todate` always define the range of `creation_date`.

Source: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/min-max

The means that with the API call you send you want the most popular tags on Stack Overflow, (desc-sorted), **created** within Aug 1 2019 (`1564617600`) and Aug 27 2019 (`1566864000`). The information returned is correct.

However, you may notice that [confluent-platform](/questions/tagged/confluent-platform) was created on Mar 9 2016. This case is quite strange, but I suspect that one of its synonyms (either [confluent](/questions/tagged/confluent) or [confluent-kafka](/questions/tagged/confluent-kafka)) was created during 2019-08-01 and 2019-08-27 and was later merged into [confluent-platform](/questions/tagged/confluent-platform) on Sep 10 2019.

---

Getting the most popular tags between a time period is not easy/possible via the Stack Exchange API. You'll probably need to use Stack Exchange Data Explorer. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1291718/most-popular-tags-during-a-time-period?fromdate=2019-08-01&todate=2019-08-27) is a query you can use.